# How to use like or search query in another model from one model?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have two model
cv and language

language model have 'cv_id' but cv doesn't have language_id.
In jquery server side processing i need to search cv with languages as well.

```
$languages = Language::where('language','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                                    ->orWhere('languageproficiency','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                                    ->pluck('id');
$results = cv::with(['languages'])->where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                                  ->orWhereIn('language',$languages)
                                  ->get();
```

**I can't write above code because cv Model doesn't have language column**
So how can i filter this.

Comment: `cv` doesn't need to have a `language_id` column for the relationship to work since it is a `hasMany`; the key is on the other table.   do you have a `languages` relationship setup on the `cv` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take an advantage of `whereHas`. That's how eloquent works.

```
$results = Cv::with(['languages'])
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
    ->orWhereHas('languages', function ($query) use ($search) {
        return $query->where('language', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('languageproficiency', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: @Watercayman What do you mean `won't work` dude? Do you see he eager load the `languages`? If he setup the relationship correctly, of course it will working.

Comment: My thinking was that OP specifically said he couldn't do it with the CV model, as it didn't have a language column.  As he said he couldn't write it the way you did (using languages as a relationship to CV), I assumed he had no relationship and thus it wouldn't work.  Looks like I was wrong - or he added the relationship.  Either way, clearly it will work just doing it normally (without the need for the extra line via reverse) now, so I will delete/retract my earlier comment. All good.

Comment: @Watercayman Oh, I see. Just take it easy bro. Btw, OP just said that he doesn't have language column in CV table, but he has `languages` relationship, that's what I get from his code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to come at it from the reverse.  Use the **Language** model which has the **CV** relation, and the Laravel `whereHas()` method, and then pull the **CV**s from that collection.

Start with a **Languages** collection:

```
 $languages = Language::where('language','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
          ->orWhere('languageproficiency','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
          ->whereHas('cv', function($query) use($search, $languages){
                    $query->where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                           ->orWhereIn('language',$languages)
          })
          ->get();
```

Then, pull the **CV**s from the language object and manipulate how you need them:

```
$results = $languages->first()->cv;
```

Or you can loop on the language object to get all of them - keep in mind that each of these results could be a collection as well.

```
$results = [];
foreach($languages as $l)
    $results[] = $l->cv;
```

Code may need review & tweaking (I'm not using my trusty editor!  And I'm not sure if you wanted to search on the `$search` term for both **Language** and **CV** or not) but, this should point you in the right direction.